# Difference between "urayamashii" and "netamashii" for "jealous"?

Tags: word-choice, words, connotation

I'm completely familiar with "urayamashii" to mean "jealous". But in Yakuza Judgement, I heard the term "netamashii" used instead. The context was that the prominent lawyer A was talking about how B's friend was gaining fame/credit, and so maybe that's why B murdered his friend, because B was "jealous" ("お前、それが妬ましかったんじゃないか？")

Is there anything to be said about the connotation of "netamashii", as opposed to "urayamashii"? Is it just a more esoteric term that self-important people might use? If you can give any similar english equivalent, that would be helpful.

Comment: @istrasci that's exactly it. Thank you so much! I should've searched up the terms in japanese.

Comment: No worries.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, both Urayamashii and Netamashii are more like envious than jealous. If you want something that another person already has, you are envious.

In any case, Netamashii is negative and Urayamashii is positive. You can say to your friend that you feel urayamashii toward her/him for his/her gorgeous house, for example. That statement acts as a praise to her/him.

On the other hand, you feel Netamashii toward a person whom you dislike. You can say Netamashii to your friend only as a joke. In such a case, your friend  will regard your Netamashii as synonymous with Urayamashii.